# Правильная проверка кода (code inspection)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, ХэшКодовцы!

Стоит задача проинспектировать некоторый достаточно объемный C++ код, который не может быть откомпилирован (нами). Т.е. грубо нам доступен исходный код и готовое решение в виде устройства, с интегрированным кодом.

Необходимо найти возможные ошибки, связанные с переполнением буфера в сим коде. Так как знания C++ у меня заканчиваются на уровне простейших задач и алгоритмов, хотя по большому счету в данном проекте больше и не нужно, хотел бы спросить, как наиболее оптимально выполнить сей поиск?

Понятное дело, что особое внимание необходимо уделить любым видам массивов и копированию памяти, но как быть оптимальным?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Воспользоваться каким-либо решением для статического анализа кода, лично я
>   рекомендую [**PVS Studio.**](http://www.viva64.com/ru/pvs-studio/)
>   Возможно, Вы также обнаружите
>   какие-либо другие ошибки, потенциально
>   приводящие к прописи в памяти.
> - Найти и тщательно проанализировать все референсы на небезопасные функции
>   типа `memset`, `memcpy` и т.п.
> - Сделать поиск по числовым константам в коде, проверить все места
>   использования переменных типа `int`,
>   `std::size_t` и их альясов, которые могут
>   потенциально приводить к вычислению
>   неправильного смещения в буферах
>   памяти, и, как следствие, ошибкам.
> - **(Идеальный вариант в вакууме)** Собрать небольшой тестовый фреймворк и
>   отдельно скомпилировать и  протестировать критичные к ошибкам  компоненты кода. В случае, если Вам  удастся реализация тестового сендбокса / `mock`-объекта, то ошибки типа `buffer overflow` можно элементарно словить
>   классическими способами - `CrtDbg` или `valgrind`. *В случае, если есть
>   тестовый фреймворк, то может также
>   подойти методика
>   [**fuzzing-тестирования.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing)*

Все, естественно, зависит от *качества `review`,* который вы надеетесь получить в итоге.

Вообще говоря, нахождение ошибок типа
`buffer overflow` в произвольно взятом
коде без возможности его
скомпилировать - это не самая простая
задача. *Может быть все-таки
существует способ каким-либо образом
собрать данный код под дебажным
рантаймом с автоматическим нахождением
`memory leak'ов` и прописей мимо
памяти?*

Comment: В том то и дело, что отказались от идеи fuzzing в пользу code inspection.

Компиляция скорее всего возможна, но на то, чтобы найти эту возможность, может уйти много времени. Код компилируется, как я понял, для конкретного устройства, поэтому нужны его (устройства) константы и прочее (я пока еще не вникал подробно). Но код огромен, полагаю, что около 3000 * 3000 строк. Из него нам необходимо проработать достаточно небольшую часть, но я не знаю насколько она зависима от остальных.

Спасибо за предложенные варианты. Идея сбора фреймворка мне понравилась, попробую так.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на страницу проекта PVS Studio. Обнаружил там хорошие разработки учебных материалов по проблемам портирования кода на 64-бит - добавлю в свой курс, студентам полезно. По поводу статического анализа: Coverity - отличный инструмент, правда, очень дорогой.